# What are pharmaceutical uses for Vanillin?

Tags: organic-chemistry, covalent-compounds

What are some pharmaceutics that use vanillin? Is vanillin just an aroma and taste agent to pharmaceutics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanillin is a pharmaceutical intermediate and flavoring, but not a pharmaceutical itself.  One can easily convert vanillin into dihydrocapsaicin (15 million Scovilles versus 16 million for capsaicin):  $\ce{NaBH3CN/NH3/NH4Cl}$, then isodecanoic amide of that benzylamine.  Surprise the downwind neighborhood.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, vanillin nowadays does not have any pharmaceutical uses.

But according to Elisabeth Vaupel in *Pharmazeutische Zeitung online*, **2002**, 38 ([SRC](http://www.pharmazeutische-zeitung.de/index.php?id=24471)), [Michael Bernhard Valentini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Bernhard_Valentini) wrote 1714 in his book *Museum Museorum, oder vollständige Schau-Bühne aller Materialien und Specereyen, nebst deren natürlichen Beschreibung*:

> Sehr erwärmende und zerteilende, anbei aber auch stärkende Kraft, womit sie den Magen stärken, die Winde zerteilen und dem Gehirn, der Mutter und anderen nervösen Gliedern sehr gut tun. Sie treiben den Harn, befördern die monatliche Reinigung, natürliche Geburt und Schwierungen: Treiben auch die Nachgeburt und tote Kinder fort und kommen also dem weiblichen Geschlecht in ihren meisten Krankheiten wohl zu pass. Ingleichen werden sie gegen die erstarrend-machenden giftigen Bisse and andere dergleichen giftige Sachen gebraucht [...] Am meisten aber werden die Vanillen zu Verfertigung der Chocolaten gebraucht, welche sie anmutiger und kräftiger machen. Die Tabaksbrüder brauchen sie auch, den Tabak wohlriechend zu machen.

As a starting material in synthesis, vanillin can be converted to [MMDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMDA_%28drug%29) in 5 steps.